# How do I show the publishing date instead of the creation date?

Tags: 7

When I create an article and I don't publish it, so I could edit the article later and publish it when it's finished, I notice Drupal shows the creation date, not the publishing date.

Is there a way to change it so the items on the front page show their publishing date and not the creation date? Is there a different field in the database for that functionality?

I am using the Workbench module, which gives draft nodes. If nodes are not published, it will display them in a draft list.

Comment: may be if you create a revision in contentype settings, this way you have a record on every change.

Comment: How to get published date?

Comment: @steniya from the node_revision table I suppose.

Comment: I checked with node, am getting only published date and changed date. If I take changed date, there is a issue. Suppose record "A" is created on Sept 10 and it is published on Sept 15, then I updated the record on Sept 25. It will display the date as Sept 25 but the record got published on Sept 15. How I can display Sept 15?

Comment: would it be acceptable to you to UPDATE the creation date at the time the node becomes published (with the publish-moment being used as creation date)?

Comment: another idea is using a flag and rules, another date field could be needed, flag node on "publish event", store that date, and do not change that date if node is already flagged.

Answer (score 0):

The [Publication Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/publication_date) module adds a field on every node that shows when a node was published.

> The Publication Date module adds a "Published on" date for each node, containing the date when it was first published.
>
> Without this, the only dates available for nodes are their created date and changed date, but these are often insufficient to meet the needs of publishing workflows. Sorting nodes by their created date doesn't account for content which is held in draft form for a time while being readied for publication. Sorting nodes by their changed date fails to account for content needing minor corrections after being published.
>
> [image: screenshot]

For nodes published before the module was installed, the module will use the node creation date, as the project page itself says.

> For nodes that were published **before** the installation of this module, we can not know the exact date of publication, so `$node->published_at` will initially contain the creation date.

Comment: I have 5000 records which are already created. This module is not applicable to those records. It can use in future. Am right?

Comment: You can use this module for existing nodes. It will look for the right date.